# How to create textured objects that blend in with the background in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, illustrator-effects

Ok, so the question by itself might be a little confusing, but basically, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to create something like this:

[image: Dribbble shot from Ryan Putnam: https://dribbble.com/shots/2281530-Texture-Icons]

Or something like this: [image]

What I want to achieve is to create a texture on an object in Illustrator, so I can blend in the object with the background and give it more depth. In the second example, pay attention to the shadow on the face. It's kind of like a shadow gradient, but it blends with some grain into the full face, and I love that effect but just don't know how to achieve it, or if it has a name to look it up.

Your help will be greatly and amazingly appreciated :D

Comment: Dribbble shots by Ryan Putnam: https://dribbble.com/shots/2281530-Texture-Icons

Comment: And Kirk Wallace! https://dribbble.com/shots/2330874-Users

Comment: Art brushes? Grunge textures, and tracing the grunge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of fine texture is difficult to synthesize in Illustrator alone. I think this could be achieved using Photoshop more easily.

But, the `Brush` tool in Illustrator can produce something similar to the shadowy gradient effect in the second image.

I've created new brushes and shown what some of the dialogues look like. I believe with some experimentation you might be able to get what you're looking for.

[image: Illustrator Brushes]